# Sleeping a process and waking it up

Tags: c, linux, time, signals

I have a small code in C on a linux embedded system. I am currently executing an algorithm every 50ms.

I was proposed to use `nanosleep`, but it will make my algorithm execute a little bit longer than every 50ms: `timetorun(algorithm) + nanosleep(50ms)`.

So I went for the alarm option instead, modifying a volatile variable. To wait for the alarm I use an empty busy loop. I don't like the approach I am taking, and I think there must be a better way to do it. Any suggestions? Maybe a way to use alarm to wake up nanosleep()?

Answer (score 0):

If available, use `timerfd`.  If not, fork a second process to act as the timer.  The timer writes into a pipe at the desired interval.  Either way, your process blocks on a read from the pipe and begins the execution whenever it receives a byte.

Answer (score 0):

`nanosleep()` guarantees that the thread calling it pauses **at least** the amount specified, not exactly the amount specified.

> nanosleep()  suspends  the execution of the calling thread until
> either at least the time specified in *req has elapsed, or the
> delivery  of  a signal  that triggers the invocation of a handler in
> the calling thread or that terminates the process.

However the following trick *might* work: Sleep a little shorter than intended, then measure how much time is missing, and then call another `nanosleep()`.
The idea is that `nanosleep()` for a very short time interval *may* use busy waiting.
Still it does not guarantee that you get exactly the time you want.

Independent of all that you may also want to use real-time priorities if you have very tight timing requirements.